# akka actor is suitable for online serving system such as seach?

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, actor

i am new to scala actor programming. i encountered some questions when learning. please give me some help.

Q1. As i learned, messages in mailbox are processed by actor. But actually, the processing is executed by an underlying threadpool. then, if we implement some concurrent jobs by actor model and original java multi-thread model, the efficiency should not have much differency. am i right?

Q2. is akka actor suitable for online serving system? as i know, in a actor system, we have some extra overhead such as message enqueue/dequeue

Q3. akka provides an actor programming paradigm. it reduces issues we may make(such as deadlock ), be easy to scale up/down. if in identical  condition, we can not count on actor to make our system better than that implemented by java multi-thread model, can we?

Answer (score 2):

Overall, yes it is suitable.

A1. The most likely efficiency gain is from *re-use* of the threads in the pool. That is, creation of actors is cheaper than creation of threads.

A2. There is overhead from most abstractions; mailbox processing is no exception. Still, it is not nearly enough overhead to make a blanket statement that akka is not suitable for near-realtime systems.

A3. No, you cannot count on Akka to automatically make things better. The hope is that it will enable you to reason about concurrency in a way that helps you build a scalable system.